# Algebraic Topology, about the condition of PID in theorem 3B.5, Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I am currently reading *Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, theorem 3B.5.* The theorem stated that

If $R$ is a **principal ideal domain** and the $R$ modules $C_i$ are free, then for each $n$ there is a natural short exact sequence
$$0\to \bigoplus_{i}(H_i(C)\otimes_R H_{n-1}(C^\prime))\to H_n(C\otimes_R C^\prime)\to \bigoplus_i(Tor_R(H_i(C), H_{n-i-1}(C))\to 0$$ and this sequence splits.

However, I totally cannot see where the proof used the condition $R$ is a PID, can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Most of these sort of theorems rely on a submodule of a free module being free. This is true for modules over $\Bbb Z$ and more generally PIDs, but not commutative rings in general. Sometimes one can get away with rings which are hereditary; submodules of frees are projective.